# Spring Boot - Auto wiring service having String constructor

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

How do i `@autowire` bean class `TransactionManagerImpl` which is having 1(String) argument constructor without using `new` in spring-boot application?
Even after searching through many post i couldn't get any clue to `autowire` without using `new`

I need to `autowire` `TransactionManager`  in three different classes and the parameters are different in all three classes.

This looks like very basic scenario.

```
@Service
public class TransactionManagerImpl implements TransactionManager {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    String txnLogFile;

    @ConstructorProperties({"txnLogFile"})
    public TransactionManagerImpl(String txnLogFile) {
        this.txnLogFile= txnLogFile; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Where txnLogFile comes from? This will create singleton instance anyway. If you have 3 different implementaitons you will have to  use @Qualifier to distinct them. You can always use ApplicationContext to get whay you need and provide contrctor args there. Also you can use `@Bean` with qualifier like in answer.

Comment: txnLogFile comes from properties file. And there are three different log files. Depending on the three diff transactions i will be injecting taxLogFile to transactionManager which will write to txnLogFile

Comment: You can also use `@Value` directly on contructor argument.

Comment: @Antoniossss that will read only single value, so i have to have three impl of TransactionManager

Comment: Yep, that is why you have to either distinct those values per implementation or get beans from application context  providing required string as arg. In both cases, qualifier is needed.

Comment: @Antoniossss what if i register TransactionManager and get bean using applicationContext by passing parameter as below  ?

 `@Value("${app.type-a.txn-log-file}")
 private String txnLogFile;
 
 @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext context;
 
 TransactionManager transactionManager = context.getBean(TransactionManager.class, txnLogFile);`

Comment: That is what I am saying you can do from the beginning (my first comment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190422/discussion-between-jigar-naik-and-antoniossss).

Answer (score 2):

is there any specific requirement where you want to use @Service annotation?
if not then you can use @Bean to create a bean for TransactionManagerImpl like below.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Value("${txnLogFile}")
private String txnLogFile;

@Bean
public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new TransactionManagerImpl(txnLogFile);
 }

}
```

and remove @Service annotation from TransactionManagerImpl.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside other complications, it can be done like this

```
public TransactionManagerImpl(@Value("${txnLogFile}") String txnLogFile) {
    this.txnLogFile= txnLogFile; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i did it as below, now sure if this is the best way to do. I did not want to have three implementation just because of one variable.

> application.yaml

```
app:
   type-a:
      txn-log-file: data/type-a-txn-info.csv
   type-b:
      txn-log-file: data/type-b-txn-info.csv
   default: 
      txn-log-file: data/default/txn-info.csv
```

> MainApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(@Value("${app.default.txn-log-file}") String txnLogFile) {
        return new TransactionManagerImpl(txnLogFile);
    }

    @Bean
    public CsvService csvService(String txnLogFile) {
        return new CsvServiceImpl(txnLogFile);
    }
}
```

> TypeOneRoute.java

```
@Configuration
public class TypeOneRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${app.type-a.txn-log-file}")
    private String txnLogFile;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private TransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        transactionManager = applicationContext.getBean(TransactionManager.class, txnLogFile);
        transactionManager.someOperation();

    }
}
```

> TypeTwoRoute.java

```
@Configuration
public class TypeTwoRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${app.type-b.txn-log-file}")
    private String txnLogFile;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private TransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        transactionManager = applicationContext.getBean(TransactionManager.class, txnLogFile);
        transactionManager.create();

    }
}
```

> TransactionManager.java

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public interface TransactionManager {

    public ZonedDateTime create() throws IOException, ParseException;

}
```

> TransactionManagerImpl.java

```
public class TransactionManagerImpl implements TransactionManager {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private String txnLogFile;

    public TransactionManagerImpl(String txnLogFile) {
        this.txnLogFile = txnLogFile;
    }

    private CsvService csvService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        csvService = applicationContext.getBean(CsvService.class, txnLogFile);
    }

    public ZonedDateTime create() throws IOException, ParseException {
        try {
            csvService.createTxnInfoFile();
            return csvService.getLastSuccessfulTxnTimestamp();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Exception occured in getTxnStartDate()", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Initially TransactionManager Bean will be registered with the `app.default.txn-info.csv` and when i actually get it from `ApplicationContext` i am replacing the value with the parameter passed to get the bean from `ApplicationContext`